# Can client be responsible for on-demand creation `java.sql.Connnection`s to be managed by HikariCP (or other pool solution)?

Tags: java, kotlin, connection-pooling, hikaricp

For security reasons the configuration/details of creation of  `java.sql.Connection` is out of my hands and controlled by a library. We speficy an identifier for the connection and it returns it. I would still like to use pooling of some sort for the management of those connections - just not the creation. Is this something that can be done with either HikariCP or some other java/kotlin pooling solution?

Ideally I'm looking for a solution that allows me to pass my own connection factory into the pool which it uses to create the connections when needed.

Comment: How about just setting minimumIdle=0?

Comment: I've not used HikariCP, but it looks like the starting point is a `HikariConfig`. I want to not have that - because they are not relevant. The library I use *creates* the connections. I just want the pool to manage. Does `minimumIdle` help?

Comment: Take a look at [intercepted datasource](https://gist.github.com/brettwooldridge/dfd21934416fc2a3c865). May be give you an starting point.

Comment: Luis Muñoz: That looks promising, Thanks! Curious, did you find it by searching or have you used it or remember hearing about it? If searching, what did you look for? I want to refine my search skills.

Comment: A mix of  both ;) I intercepted connections in a pool some time ago so I searched for `hikari intercept connection`.